# Apycom Menu change sub menu css properties (colors)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, obfuscation

How do i change sub category menu properties in Apycom Menu? Everything i do with css only affects meta menu. I think it maybe their obfuscating javascript file buisness but how do i change it while using non-commercial version?

Comment: What exactly are you asking here?

Comment: The way to edit sub menu color. Or just alternative to apycom menu.

Comment: You've already said that in your question. More detail is required to give you an answer, so please give it. What do you mean by "alternative to apycom menu"?

Comment: I mean some alternative jQuery menu with the similar features.